# Recommended Meta Elements?

Tags: html, meta-tags

Setting up a "basic framework" for my website projects, I'm wondering which meta elements are really necessary/recommended? In particular, I'd like to know how to deal with the language attribute(s)!? In the following example, I think sth. is repeated unnecessarily...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />
<meta http-equiv="language" content="en" />

<title> Title </title>
<base href="http://www.mydomain.com" />

<meta name="charset" content="utf-8" />
<meta name="content-language" content="en" />
<meta name="language" content="en" />

<meta name="description" content="description" />
<meta name="keywords" content="keywords" />

</head>
```

P.S. "content-language" = "language"?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092329/what-are-the-important-meta-tags-i-must-put-in-my-website

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Definitely recommended

```
<meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css" />
```

Useless, browsers only support CSS.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript" />
```

Useless, browsers only support JavaScript.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />
```

Redundant to `<html lang="en">`

```
<meta http-equiv="language" content="en" />
```

Doesn't exist, AFAIK.

```
<title> Title </title>
```

Definitely recommended.

```
<base href="http://www.mydomain.com" />
```

Depends on how you want your relative links to work, I suppose.

```
<meta name="charset" content="utf-8" />
<meta name="content-language" content="en" />
<meta name="language" content="en" />
```

Look like typo's.

```
<meta name="description" content="description" />
```

Probably useful.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="keywords" />
```

Ignored by every search engine due to widespread abuse.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for HTML 5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This looks wrong:

```
<meta name="charset" content="utf-8" />
```

should probably be this for HTML 5:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

That is the new HTML 5-way of setting charset encoding. It is highly recommended to also include the old way:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

These should be directly after the opening head-tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>The title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```