# How can I avoid the "Bad value language for attribute name on element meta" HTML validation error?

Tags: html, w3c-validation, meta

I'm getting this error when I validate my HTML using [the W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/):

```
Bad value language for attribute name on element meta: Keyword language is not registered.

<meta name="language" content="en" />
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874947/recommended-meta-elements here is the questions which gives good description

Comment: "How can I solve this?" By *not* using `language` as a value for the `name` attribute on the `meta` tag.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use

```
<html lang="en">
```

[Source](http://nimbupani.com/declaring-languages-in-html-5.html)

Answer (score 3):

You should specify the language on the HTML tag, like so:

```
<html lang="en">
```

You can also ues the `lang` attribute on any element, so if you have just one div with French in it, you could do:

```
<html lang="en">
    ...
    <body>
        ...
        <div lang="fr"></div>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for content-language

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
```

Comment: I used that. Now i'm getting error as:
Using the meta element to specify the document-wide default language is obsolete. Consider specifying the language on the root element instead.
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />

Comment: In this case you have to use ``<html lang="en">`` as already replied by several other persons.

Comment: @Veena: see [@AshBurlaczenko's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15969876/20578)

Comment: `Bad value Content-Language for attribute name on element meta: Keyword content-language is not registered.`

The Content-Language value for an http-equiv attribute on a meta element should no longer be used. You should use a language attribute on the html tag to declare the default language of the actual text in the page.