# What meta tags should I include in my website?

Tags: html, seo, meta-tags

## What meta tags should I include in my website?

**What are the most common meta tags and relevance?**
e.i. what the benefit to including `<meta charset="utf-8">`

**What is the proper way to declare meta tags?**
Should they also be declared in the head tag? Is `<meta charset="utf-8">` the same as `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` and if so which is better?

**What are best practices for the most common scenarios?**

**Who sees what?**

Which tags are meant for the browsers, search engine, etc.

I would really like to compile a detailed list of best practices and explanations regarding meta tags, so please elaborated and explain as much as possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the important meta tags I must put in my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092329/what-are-the-important-meta-tags-i-must-put-in-my-website)

Comment: Agreed, those are probably the most important to have in your site.

Answer (score 2):

`<meta>` is not xhtml compliant that is now a popular and recommended standard but `<meta/>` is.
So use `<meta/>`

charset meta tag defines what character set HTML browsers and XML processors should use internally to process data.

For the most common scenarios, include title (not exactly a meta tag but extremely important for SEO), description, keywords and robots meta tag.

`<meta name="resource-type" content="document">` is also expected to be used in near future by search engines to filter the web by content. (Leading search engines have just started a shared project for this).

For the complete browser and search engine specific meta tags list, try googling it.
Btw, here is the summary:
Browser uses:

```
- title
- language
- refresh
```

Search Engine

```
- title
- keyword
- description
- author
- expires
- revisit
- robots
```